# A JSpinner with min and max buttons

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I'm looking for a JSpinner-like component that would provide built-in buttons that would immediately set the spinner value to the minimum or the maximum of the jspinner model. Before implementing this myself, I thought that somebody might have done it before, though my google searches on the topic were not successful.

Is there such a component out there, or should I code it myself ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of any component that would do it out of the box. But basically, a simple flow layout with a minus button, a spinner and a max button would do. Both buttons would have `actionListeners` that will ask the spinner for min and max values and set its value.

Use a changeListener on the spinner to be notified of value changes both programatically (using your buttons) and through user interaction.

Also, you could consider using a JCombobox if your values are discrete or a JSlider if they are not, as both components present upper and lower bounds more clearly to users.

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid there was no ready-to-use component. I'll implement it.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be simple to implemt it by yourself

1) I would create a class that extend JPanel.

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel
```

2) In this class you have to define where your slider and buttons have to be placed and the actions correlated to the button.

```
public MyPanel(){
  super();
  // set the layout
  JSlider slider = new Slider();
  this.add(slider);
  // ..
  JButton button1 = new JButton();
  //
}
```

3) You can add to your application JPanel instances of the class the you have implemented.

Answer (score 2):

you have to read [How to Use Spinners](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) , and then you can be able set these value exactly for [SpinnerNumberModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerNumberModel.html#SpinnerNumberModel%28java.lang.Number,%20java.lang.Comparable,%20java.lang.Comparable,%20java.lang.Number%29)

```
JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 20, 1));
```

for example (by StanislavL)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class TestDigitsOnlySpinner {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater((Runnable) new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("enter digit");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                JSpinner jspinner = makeDigitsOnlySpinnerUsingDocumentFilter();
                frame.getContentPane().add(jspinner, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame.getContentPane().add(new JButton("just another widget"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

            private JSpinner makeDigitsOnlySpinner_BasicAttempt() {
                JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel());
                return spinner;
            }

            private JSpinner makeDigitsOnlySpinnerUsingDocumentFilter() {
                JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 20, 1));
                JSpinner.NumberEditor jsEditor = (JSpinner.NumberEditor) spinner.getEditor();
                final Document jsDoc = jsEditor.getTextField().getDocument();
                if (jsDoc instanceof PlainDocument) {
                    AbstractDocument doc = new PlainDocument() {

                        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                        @Override
                        public void setDocumentFilter(DocumentFilter filter) {
                            if (filter instanceof MyDocumentFilter) {
                                super.setDocumentFilter(filter);
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    doc.setDocumentFilter(new MyDocumentFilter());
                    jsEditor.getTextField().setDocument(doc);
                }
                return spinner;
            }
        });
    }

    private static class MyDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter {

        @Override
        public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
            if (stringContainsOnlyDigits(string)) {
                super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void remove(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length) throws BadLocationException {
            super.remove(fb, offset, length);
        }

        @Override
        public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
            if (stringContainsOnlyDigits(text)) {
                super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
            }
        }

        private boolean stringContainsOnlyDigits(String text) {
            for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
                if (!Character.isDigit(text.charAt(i))) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    private TestDigitsOnlySpinner() {
    }
}
```