# Help in automatically changing value upon ItemChange in JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, listener, jcombobox, parseint

I have a program in which I am using 3 things, a checkbox, a combobox and a textfield. The logic works like this if checkbox is enable then combobox and textfield are enable unless not.

Then set some value in the textfield by mulitplying it with the item in combobox.

[image: The JFrame that I am working on]

From the frame  - The value of Final Price is Price * Quantity.

Now the issue when I click purchase everything went fine. But when I change the value from Jcombobox it doesn't automatically change the value in final price and remains to be 1200 as in first case. For the value to be changed I have uncheck and then check the Checkbox.

What could be the problem. I have used ItemListner for both checkbox and combobox.

```
@Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){

    Object get = e.getSource();

    int multiplier;
    int ftotal;


    if (e.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED){
        if(get==chkbox1){
             qntbox1.setEnabled(true);            
             size1.setEnabled(true);
             multiplier = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(qntbox1.getSelectedItem()));


             ftotal = Integer.parseInt(price1.getText()) * multiplier;
             fprice1.setText(String.valueOf(ftotal));}
```

Comment: That screenshot did not require 1) the image at the top 2) rows 2 through 7 of the fields 3) The border around the image, or.. 4) in fact the screenshot itself conveys nothing beyond what could be described as text.  In future, please consider *not* including a screenshot of such problems, and if you think one *is* appropriate, use the advice in the [How do I create a screenshot to illustrate a post? FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to implement `ActionListener` for your `JComboBox`:

```
private static final String command_cbo1 = "ComboBox1";
// ...

public class YourClass implements ItemListener, ActionListener
{
    // ...

    public YourClass()
    {
        // ...
        qntbox1.addActionListener(this);
        qntbox1.setActionCommand(command_cbo1);
        // ...
    }

    // ...

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)        
    {
        // ...
    }

    // ...

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JComboBox cb = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
        String s = (String) cb.getSelectedItem();

        if(e.getActionCommand().equals(command_cbo1))
        {
            fprice1.setText("" + (Integer.parseInt(price1.getText()) * Integer.parseInt(s)));
        }
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. But I think its doesn't matter whether we implement ActionListner of ItemListner. The thing that matter is a change in state of the combobox and that is being fulfilled by ItemListener. Will consider you code and will revert later.

Answer (score 1):

not directly to your question

1/ [JCheckBox](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#checkbox) is totally useless, that will be really needed for final calculation(s)

2/ consider that [JComponents](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) for `Price` and `Final Price` would be only [JFormattedTextField](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html), then you can pretty to forgot for `Parse#Whatever`

3/ consider that `JComponents` for `Quantity` would be only [JSpinner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html), but workaround for Number Instance would be litte bit complicated as for `JFormattedTextField` example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911165/a-jspinner-with-min-and-max-buttons/6911410#6911410)

4/ for nice output put everything to the [JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

5/ for [JComboBox](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) I preferred [ItemListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html) not [ActionListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html), because your problems isn't with proper `Listener` but with parsing `Numbers` correct way

Comment: Thanks, will consider your suggestions and will implement it. 

The issue is, I don't really have much time to experiment and thus was thinking of doing something nifty. But since JComboBox is not working as in my case I'll look into tabular and spinner components.

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it working. The ActionListner made it work (JComboBox). I guess using ItemListner for too many components made parsing a little confusing, add to that I used too many clauses in the ItemListner scope. Thanks a lot everyone for helping.

@mKorbel : I'll be using your suggestion asap :) and will check JTable and said components. have to go through them since I haven't used it.

@Eng.Fouad : Thanks man for the help.

Just one issue. When I typecast getSelectedItem() to integer it gives NumberFormatException error (runtime). So I have to first change the object to String and then parseit into integer. Any clue why direct conversion is throwing error ?

Here is the working code for the project.

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){

    Object get = e.getSource();



    if (e.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED){
        if(get==chkbox1){
             qntbox1.setEnabled(true);            
             size1.setEnabled(true);   
             fprice1.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(price1.getText()) * Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(qntbox1.getSelectedItem()))));
        }
  @Override
       public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae)
       {

          Object toggel = ae.getSource();      
          String check;

          if (toggel == qntbox1)
          {
            check = (String) qntbox1.getSelectedItem();
            fprice1.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(price1.getText()) * Integer.parseInt(check)));

          }
```